# SQL - check date in column 1 and if it is null, then compare date in column 2 with another row to return the date that is later

Tags: sql

```
    personsID          traindate          expirationdate     trainingID
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                  1/1/2014           null               3
    1                  2/1/2014           null               3
    1                  3/1/2014           4/1/2014           3
    1                  4/1/2014           4/30/2014          4
    1                  5/1/2014           5/30/2014          4
```

I have been trying to figure out how to write this query for several days now, but have not been successful. I have tried case, (NULLIF(MAX(COALESCE(, max, subqueries and several others but cannot figure out how to return the results I need.

What I need the query to do is return 1 row per training id based on the expriation date and then the training date. In other words, the query needs to first look at the expirationdate column and if the value is null then retrieve the last traindate. If the expirationdate is not null then return the last expirationdate. In the example above I would need the results to be:

```
    personsID          traindate          expirationdate     trainingID
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                  2/1/2014           null               3
    1                  5/1/2014           5/30/2014          4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What DB engine and why 2 records and not just one?

Comment: I'm unclear on the logic. I would expect from the text that you would want 1, 3/1/2013, null, 3 as the first row in you sample.

Comment: This is more complex than i thought.   Are the rows in your data set, in order as shown?   Karl is correct.  3/1/2014 is the last train date in id 3

Comment: What DB engine: I am using MS-sql.  The reason I need to retrieve 2 records is because it represents 2 training records for the same person.

Comment: The order in the actual dataset is not in the order shown. The training date and expiration date could be in any order. The reason I need record 1 2/1/2014 null 3 instead of 1 3/1/2014 4/1/2014 3 is because the 2/1/2014 record doesn't expire while the 3/1/2014 record will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumption (see question comment) is correct then this would do it in SQL Server.

EDIT: OP has clarified is need. I've included his desired result two different ways, but I think I prefer the option2.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(personsID INT
                  ,traindate DATE
                  ,expirationdate DATE
                  ,trainingID INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
  (1,'1/1/2014',null,3)
 ,(1,'2/1/2014',null,3)
 ,(1,'3/1/2014','4/1/2014',3)
 ,(1,'4/1/2014','4/30/2014',4)
 ,(1,'5/1/2014','5/30/2014',4)

SELECT personsID
      ,trainingID
      ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                          FROM @tbl a 
                         WHERE a.personsID=b.personsID 
                           AND a.trainingID =b.trainingID
                           AND a.expirationdate IS NULL) 
            THEN (SELECT MAX(traindate) 
                          FROM @tbl a 
                         WHERE a.personsID=b.personsID 
                           AND a.trainingID =b.trainingID
                           AND a.expirationdate IS NULL )             
            ELSE MAX(traindate) 
       END maxtraindatethatdoesntexpire_option1
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 
               traindate 
          FROM @tbl a 
         WHERE a.personsID=b.personsID 
           AND a.trainingID =b.trainingID
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.expirationdate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
                 ,traindate DESC
       ) maxtraindatethatdoesntexpire_option2
      ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                          FROM @tbl a 
                         WHERE a.personsID=b.personsID 
                          AND a.trainingID =b.trainingID
                          AND a.expirationdate IS NULL) 
            THEN NULL               
            ELSE MAX(expirationdate)
       END expirationdate
FROM @tbl b
GROUP BY personsID,trainingID
```

ORIGINAL:

The tricky part is using the CASE WHEN EXISTS to handle the NULL expiration date. Other than that it looks to be a matter of

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(personsID INT
                  ,traindate DATE
                  ,expirationdate DATE
                  ,trainingID INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
  (1,'1/1/2014',null,3)
 ,(1,'2/1/2014',null,3)
 ,(1,'3/1/2014','4/1/2014',3)
 ,(1,'4/1/2014','4/30/2014',4)
 ,(1,'5/1/2014','5/30/2014',4)

SELECT personsID
      ,trainingID
      ,MAX(traindate) traindate
      ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                          FROM @tbl a 
                         WHERE a.personsID=b.personsID 
                           AND a.trainingID =b.trainingID
                           AND a.expirationdate IS NULL) 
            THEN NULL               
            ELSE MAX(expirationdate)
       END expirationdate
FROM @tbl b
GROUP BY personsID,trainingID
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the above didn't quite work. It returned the correct record for training record 4 (1,'5/1/2014','5/30/2014',4), but not for training ID 3. It returned the row with the 3/1/2014 training date, but I need it to return the 2/1/2014 row that has the null expiration date. This is the latest training date that will never expire.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. As you can imagine the actual completed query is much more complicated than what I asked within my question. But, you gave me a GREAT start – THANKS!!!

Comment: Happy to help. It is pretty standard to try to post a simplified version that represent you scenario as you have done, so good job on your first question. Since this was useful and answered you question, please up vote and accept the answer to close out the loop.

Comment: I marked the question as answered and tried to up your vote, but the message is that it "requires a 15 reputation" and would not let me change it. You did answer my question, but I am not sure what to do now for you now. Is there a way to up the vote?